# converting obstructive to unobstructive html

Tags: javascript, html

hello I am fairly new to html and javascript I am currently learning about obstructive javascript and unobstructive javascript I would like to know the difference and use this example to put it into unobstructive javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").html("I am fine");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>How are you doing?.</p>
<button id="b1">Answer</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sure it's not 'unobtrusive' js?

Comment: sorry for the spelling error